# Parsing headers in Safari - something similar to Live HTTP Headers for Firefox?

Tags: http, safari, http-headers

I need to resolve a weird issue with Safari playing back mp3 files as streaming files although the entire length of the content and all of the content is provided to the browser...

Apparently, I will have to address Range headers, which is a new topic for me.

How would I monitor the headers being sent and received in Safari? Is there a plugin or some other trick I can use? I have developer mode turned on so I can inspect elements, but I don't know how to monitor headers.

M

Comment: regarding your initial problem see `Content-Disposition` header <http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1>

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

Inspect Elements > Resources pane

At this point, you may see a window that says, "You need to enable resource tracking to use this panel" and offers you a choice of "Only enable for this session" or "Always enable." Either is fine, and then click "Enable resource tracking."

In the resulting window, find the resource you want the header for and select it.

On the right hand side, there should now be a header with two tabs: "Headers" and "Content." If it's not already selected, choose "Headers."

You should then see the headers (as Safari received them) for your selected resource. To look at another resource's header, just select that, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. My issue now is - I get nothing for the item I am interested in. I have a PHP file that retrieves the audio from a mySQL database... The request for the file that delivers the audio content shows up as a resource, but not the audio itself. There must be another way for me to capture and display the headers returned by SAfari...

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Safari 5.1, you can view HTTP headers in the Network tab of the Web Inspector:

1. Enable the Develop menu in Preferences -> Advanced, if it isn't already.
2. From your web page, choose Show Web Inspector from the Develop menu.
3. Switch to the Network tab.
4. Reload the page.

You can then select on the resource on the left and click "Headers."

*In older Safari versions, this information was in the Web Inspector's Resources tab.*